# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'props') React Native Unittesting

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, typeerror

I'm trying to do a unit test for my React-Native application by using Jest and testing-library/react-native but i get a TypeError and i can't solve the problem.

This is my Component code:

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Swiper from "react-native-deck-swiper";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { styles } from "./StyledSwipe.js";

function* range(start, end) {    
 
 for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
   yield i;
 }
}

export default class Exemple extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [...range(1, 50)],  
      swipedAllCards: false,
      swipeDirection: "",
      cardIndex: 0,
    };
    this.swiper = {};
  }

  renderCard = (card, index) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          {card}   
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  onSwiped = (type) => {
    console.log(`on swiped ${type}`);
  };

  onSwipedAllCards = () => {
    this.setState({
      swipedAllCards: true,
    });
  };

  swipeLeft = () => {
    this.swiper.swipeLeft();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Swiper
        testID="swipe"
          ref={(swiper) => {
            this.swiper = swiper;
          }}
          onSwiped={() => this.onSwiped("general")}
          onSwipedLeft={() => this.onSwiped("left")}
          onSwipedRight={() => this.onSwiped("right")}
          onSwipedTop={() => this.onSwiped("top")}
          onSwipedBottom={() => this.onSwiped("bottom")}
          onTapCard={this.swipeLeft}
          cards={this.state.cards}
          cardIndex={this.state.cardIndex}
          cardVerticalMargin={80}
          renderCard={this.renderCard}
          onSwipedAll={this.onSwipedAllCards}
          stackSize={3}
          stackSeparation={15}
          overlayLabels={{
            bottom: {
              title: "BLEAH",
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  borderColor: "black",
                  color: "white",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                },
              },
            },
            left: {
              title: "NOPE",
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  borderColor: "black",
                  color: "white",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  alignItems: "flex-end",
                  justifyContent: "flex-start",
                  marginTop: 30,
                  marginLeft: -30,
                },
              },
            },
            right: {
              title: "LIKE",
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  borderColor: "black",
                  color: "white",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  alignItems: "flex-start",
                  justifyContent: "flex-start",
                  marginTop: 30,
                  marginLeft: 30,
                },
              },
            },
            top: {
              title: "SUPER LIKE",
              style: {
                label: {
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  borderColor: "black",
                  color: "white",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                },
                wrapper: {
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                },
              },
            },
          }}
          animateOverlayLabelsOpacity
          animateCardOpacity
          swipeBackCard
        >
        <Button 
        testID="tillbaka"
        style={styles.backButton}
        onPress={() => this.swiper && this.swiper.swipeBack()}
        title="Tillbaka" />
      </Swiper>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My Test:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, getByText, getByTestId, queryByTestId} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Exemple, {onTapCard, onSwiped, swipeBack, swipeLeft} from './Swipe.js';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper';
  
describe('Exemple component', () => {

  test("logs swipe direction", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(console, "log");
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<Exemple/>);
    const swiper = queryByTestId("swiper");
    console.log(swiper)

    fireEvent(swiper, "onSwipedLeft");

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("on swiped left");

    spy.mockClear();
      expect(swiper.props.swipedAllCards).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

and the TypeError i get:

```
 Exemple component › logs swipe direction

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'props')

      18 |     console.log(swiper)
      19 |
    > 20 |     fireEvent(swiper, "onSwipedLeft");
         |              ^
      21 |
      22 |     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("on swiped left");
      23 |

      at props (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/fireEvent.ts:95:22)
      at getEventHandler (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/fireEvent.ts:79:19)
      at findEventHandler (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/fireEvent.ts:112:19)
      at invokeEvent (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/fireEvent.ts:143:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/Swipe/Swipe.test.js:20:14)
```

I tried using "getByTestId" instead of "queryByTestId" but it did not work. Console.log(swiper) returns null.

Answer (score 0):

check the `const swiper = queryByTestId("swiper");` and  `testID="swipe"`.

Comment: Thanks, i changed testID to "swiper" and then i get another error:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'props')

      37 |     console.log(swiper)
      38 |
    > 39 |     fireEvent(swiper, "onSwipedLeft");
         |              ^
      40 |
      41 |     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("on swiped left");
      42 |